# Webpack, vue.js and component bundles separation

Tags: node.js, module, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

We are trying to build a 'pluginisable' Java webapp which use vue.js on client-side.

### General description

Let say we want to get the following server-side application simplified architecture without NodeJs in production (and using Java and Osgi but it doesn't really matter here in my opinion, it may be PHP, .Net or wathever) :

- A main webapp which exposes, among others : vuejs2, router and some general dependencies (bootstrap, jQuery etc...) on the client-side,
- Many webapp plugins which expose, among others : additional and/or optional vue.js components and third party dependencies.

### What we want

The webapp does the work to check for available webapp plugins on server-side and then expose the appropriate JS files in the index file. For example :

- app.js : the main webapp loader and general dependencies,
- pluginA.js : the vue.js components provided by the server-side plugin "A",
- pluginB.js : the vue.js components provided by the server-side plugin "B".

The entire webapp is not build through nodejs but each of the 3 examples are built separately using node and webpack.

### Constraints

How can we achieve a build process for the plugins following these constraints :

- we want to avoid the javascript build process to have to conciliate all parts of the application at the same time : **Checked**, we have 1 embedded vue app per webapp plugin, Maven runs the node build process for each webapp plugin and the server-side already does the job to expose all of the 3 files separately,
- the plugin JS files only contain the built vue components and 3rd-party dependencies that they want to provide : **Not checked**, all of the 3 output folders contains all the JS dependencies.

### Line of thought

For each webapp plugin, we think we need to find a way to build all .vue files of a webapp plugin and exclude all other dependencies from the output file. As we are new to the node and vuejs world, how could we achieve this ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try code splitting:

> Code splitting is the idea that a bundle [a `.js` file with all your Vue.js code bundled together] can be fragmented into smaller files allowing the user to only download what code they need, when they need it.
>
> (...)
>
> The key to code splitting a Vue.js app is async components. These are components where the component definition (including its template, data, methods etc) is loaded asynchronously.
>
> (...)
>
> We’ll need Webpack’s help to dynamically load [components]. (...) Webpack has an implementation [of an] import() [method] and treats it as a code split point, putting the requested module into a separate file when the bundle is created.

Source: [Code Splitting With Vue.js And Webpack](http://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/07/03/vue-js-code-splitting-webpack/), a very helpful guide for implementing code splitting.

Below is the `main.js` code that the author of the guide ends up with to dynamically load a component. If I read the guide correctly, this change in the way you register a component is the only change necessary to implement code splitting. No changes are necessary in your Webpack config.

```
new Vue({ 
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    ExampleAsyncComponent: () => import('./ExampleAsyncComponent.vue') /* This is the changed part. */
  }
});
```

Comment: This suggestion is very interresting and opens some other ways to think about a solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Badacadabra Thanks for the tip, I've updated my answer with a summary of the guide.